Confused and wrong code when uploading image in NextJS
I'm developing a backend for my app using Next.js, and Prisma. I'm having trouble trying to create a new product by uploading an image using multer. When I send a POST request with multipart/form-data, I get the following error, Oh yes, when a user wants to upload an image, the image will be renamed using MD5, and will be saved in the public/images folder
How can I fix this error?
{"error":"Error creating product: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')"}
this i use form-data
this i use raw but its success
heres the code
in api/products/route.js
import express from 'express';
import prisma from '@/libs/prisma';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { multerMiddleware } from '@/libs/multerConfig';

const app = express();
app.use(multerMiddleware)


const runMiddleware = (req, res, fn) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (result) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result);
      }
      return resolve(result);
    });
  });
};

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const products = await prisma.product.findMany();
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(products), {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Error fetching products' }), {
      status: 500,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  }
}

export async function POST(req, res) {
  const contentType = req.headers.get('content-type');

  if (contentType.includes('application/json')) {
    try {

      const body = await req.json();
      const { nama, deskripsi, harga, stok, kategori, tokoId, image } = body;

      if (!nama || !deskripsi || !harga || !stok || !kategori || !tokoId || !image) {
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'All fields are required' }), { status: 400 });
      }

      const newProduct = await prisma.product.create({
        data: {
          nama,
          deskripsi,
          harga,
          stok,
          kategori,
          tokoId,
          image,
        },
      });

      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(newProduct), { status: 201 });
    } catch (error) {
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Error creating product: ' + error.message }), { status: 500 });
    }
   } else if (contentType.includes('multipart/form-data')) {
    try {
      await runMiddleware(req, res, multerMiddleware);
      console.log('req.body:', req.body);  // Should be a JSON object now
      console.log('req.files:', req.files);

      const { nama, deskripsi, harga, stok, kategori, tokoId } = req.body;
      const image = req.files.image[0]? `/images/${req.files.image[0].filename}` : null;


      if (!nama || !deskripsi || !harga || !stok || !kategori || !tokoId) {
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'All fields are required', body: req.body, file: req.file }), { status: 400 });
      }

      const newProduct = await prisma.product.create({
        data: {
          nama,
          deskripsi,
          harga,
          stok,
          kategori,
          tokoId,
          image,
        },
      });

      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(newProduct), { status: 201 });
    } catch (error) {
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Error creating product: ' + error.message }), { status: 500 });
    }
  } else {
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Unsupported content type' }), { status: 415 });
  }
}

in libs/multerConfig.js
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
import crypto from 'crypto';

// Multer configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/images');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const md5sum = crypto.createHash('md5').update(file.originalname + Date.now()).digest('hex');
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, `${md5sum}${ext}`);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|webp|heic/;
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error('Only images are allowed'));
  }
};

export const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});

const formParser = upload.fields([{ name: 'image', maxCount: 1 }]); 

export const multerMiddleware = formParser;

this is the prisma database model
model Product {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  nama        String
  deskripsi   String?
  harga       Float
  stok        Int
  kategori    String
  tokoId      Int
  image       String?
  toko        Toko     @relation(fields: [tokoId], references: [id])
  orderDetails OrderDetail[]
  reviews      Review[]
}

this is the console.log from req.body and req.file
req.body: ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
req.files: undefined
POST /api/products 500 in 12ms
I used postman as I said and the photo I sent just now
